# Remove characters from the last column of a list of data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list `listDF` of 30 data frames (~1000 rows X 3 columns). In the last column of each one, I have a composite character as shown below :

```
Date        Origin              Chemical
28/10/2012  Artificial nuclides Cs-137__Sea
28/10/2012  Natural nuclides    Ra-226__Clouds
28/10/2012  Natural nuclides    Ra-228__Sands
28/10/2012  Natural nuclides    Th-228__Sea
28/10/2012  Artificial nuclides Cs-137__Rocks
```

For the last column of each df, how can I simply remove "__Sea", "__Clouds"... and just keep the chemical name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may also be done with `trimws` from `base R`

```
listDF <- lapply(listDF, transform, 
      Chemical = trimws(Chemical, whitespace = "__.*"))
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
listDF <- map(listDF, mutate, Chemical = str_remove(Chemical, "__.*"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R solution:

```
## requires R version 4.1 or higher
listDF = lapply(listDF,
  \(df) {
    df[["Chemical"]] = sub(pattern = "__.*", replacement = "", df[["Chemical"]])
    df
  })
```

```
## any R version
listDF = lapply(listDF,
  function(df) {
    df[["Chemical"]] = sub(pattern = "__.*", replacement = "", df[["Chemical"]])
    df
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. It seems that there is an issue with the "\". Do you have a general approach if I wish to tackle this issue for the column "Chemical" but the df's may be of different lengths (different number of columns) ?

Comment: To use the `\(df)` syntax you need a relatively recent version of R. I updated to include an older version, and changed to use column name instead of column number.

Answer (score 0):

For-loop solution:

```
for (df in listDF){
  for (i in 1:nrow(listDF)){
    df[i, "Chemical"] = unlist(strsplit(df[i, "Chemical"], "__"))[1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I got : Error in 1:nrow(listDF) :   argument of length 0.

Comment: If `listDF` is a `list`, then `nrow()` won't work on it. I think what you have would more-or-less work on a single data frame, but on a single data frame `strsplit` is vectorized so the `for` loop wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't properly read the description and thought the question was about a single dataframe. I've edited my solution to a double for-loop which is inefficient, but easy to understand.